# Android error: Execution failed for task ':app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug'.

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am developing an Android app and have been running it on a phone for a while.  Randomly I got this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug'.
> No current or previous main artifacts. This should not happen.
```

I have tried clearing .gradle caches, Invalidate Caches / Restart to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It worked after running the app on a virtual device then re-running it on the physical device. Weird bug.

Comment: I also had this today, from one day to another without changing anything. A `Build -> Clean Project` helped.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a random issue... Restart or Clean Project works always...

Answer (score 0):

what i do is just clean the project and rebuild it again, you can find it on **Build -> Clean Project**. Then wait it until finish, after finish you can continue to Rebuild the project on **Build -> Rebuild Project**